# combinatorics distribution problem solution

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know a way to solve distribution problem where n distinct objects are to be distributed to r distinct boxes/person with partition unspecified.I did not find any such case in any book till now.But I somehow found formula to be applied is r power(n).I do not know how this formula applies to my problem and where did it came from.Can anyone help me and also guide me to good reading material for distribution problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree; in fact, your formula here should be $r^n$.  Why?  Because for each of your $n$ objects, you have to choose $1$ of the $r$ possible boxes... and choices for one object do not affect the rest.

Comment: Yes you are right I made a mistake in writing.